# JBoss is taking a long time to read faces-config on the startup

Tags: jsf, jboss, faces-config

The startup of my local application (JSF 1.1 on JBoss 4.0.5 GA) is taking forever (over 9 minutes!). It stops while reading the faces-config.xml:

==> INFO  [FacesConfigurator] Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml (it gets stuck here)

A few days ago everything was working just fine. I tried to revert the few changes that were made to the faces-config file but the problem persists.

Any ideas on what can be going on or things I could do to help me with the troubleshooting?

Thanks

Comment: You should remove your *editing* from your question and post it as an answer, then after two days you must accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found out that the problem was with the schema validation. I removed the following line from my faces-config.xml and it worked:

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"